# Generic parameter depending on Media query

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

So Im currently in a situation where I need to change a specific parameter value of a component when Im on a mobile device. for instance:

```
@media all and (max-width: 720px)
```

Which is being used with scss

And I have this component which takes some parameter when being used;

```
<Books pageLimit={10} />
```

So in my case I want to change the value of the property from 10 to 4 when its

720px resoultion device (@media all and (max-width: 720px) or below.

I am quite new to media query and styling etc. So Im not sure of how to fix this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a window `resize` event listener and change a piece of state when the width of the window is below `720px`.

**Example** (Click `Full page` to see it in action)

```js
function Books({ pageLimit }) {
  return <div>{pageLimit}</div>;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    pageLimit: window.innerWidth < 720 ? 4 : 10
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.resize);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.resize);
  }

  resize = () => {
    this.setState({ pageLimit: window.innerWidth < 720 ? 4 : 10 });
  };

  render() {
    return <Books pageLimit={this.state.pageLimit} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```